# How to add support for special character like (ą ę ó ÿ ż, etc) to file-io via getBasename()

Tags: php, file-io, utf-8

I need to modify the function below for better international character support.

It reads a directory of .txt files and imports those files into the site using file_get_contents() and getBasename(). This works really well until the filename sent to the getBasename() method contains special characters like ą ę ó ÿ ż, etc.

For example, in Polish, the "Privacy Policy.txt" file is named Polityka prywatnoÿci.txt

But, when its imported into the site, the page name becomes: Polityka prywatno

You can see that its cut off at the ÿ

How can I modify this function to support character sets like that?

```
function insert_pages(){
DEFINE ('PAGES', dirname(__FILE__).'/pages/');
$directory_pages = new DirectoryIterator(PAGES); 
foreach ($directory_pages as $files_pages) 
    {
    if ($files_pages->isFile()) 
        {
        $file_name_page = $files_pages->getFilename();
        $my_page_content = file_get_contents(PAGES. $file_name_page);
        $my_page['post_content'] = addslashes($my_page_content);
        $my_page['post_title'] = $files_pages->getBasename('.txt');
        $my_page['post_type'] = 'page';
        $my_page['post_status'] = 'publish';
        wp_insert_post($my_page);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the character encoding of your file

Comment: you can convert a filename into a entities and import in site.http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/entities.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php file system functions accept , return file names in ISO-8859-1

Use `is_file(utf8_decode($filename))` , will change UTF-8 character with representable character  in ISO-8859-1.

Your characters are multi-byte characters and PHP5 is not capable of addressing them

Comment: +1 That's 1/2 of the problem. The other half is that when WordPress plugins manager transfers the file, it renames it to Polityka prywatnoy''ci.txt